# SELF_REFRESH not working in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I working on touch UI component development and my cq:editConfig seems not to be working. The problem I am facing is Once I edit the dialog in component, its not getting reflect automatically but I have to refersh the page manually to see the effective changes.

Any idea if it is related to specific version? Here is the xml file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_SELF"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: It should work. see the example component implementation from `/libs/foundation/components/carousel/cq:editConfig/cq:listeners`. If possible update the component dialog how you have created.

Comment: @VAr I am using almost same code (updated in the question). Its still not  working .

Comment: can you give a try with `REFRESH_PAGE`, and see if it refreshes page.? I have tested the same `/libs/foundation/components/carousel/cq:editConfig/cq:listen‌​ers` component in gemotrixx page both `REFRESH_SELF` and `REFRESH_PAGE` works fine for me.

Comment: @VAr facing same issue with REFRESH_PAGE too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this line to my header lib to make it work:

`<!--/* Initialize the Authoring UI */-->
<sly data-sly-include="author.html" />`